# Seasonal Image Changer (MVC & JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, image

I am trying to implement a function in my MVC app that changes the main logo based on the Month of the year using JavaScript.

I am setting the image in my Layout.cshtml view as shown:

`<img id="logo" src="~/Images/Logos/default.png" alt="Logo" style="max-width: 300px" />`

My javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var d = new Date();
    var Month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var img = document.getElementById("logo");
    var src;

    switch (Month) {
        default:
            src = "Images/Logos/default.png";   // Set Default Logo
            break;
        case 12:
            src = "Images/Logos/Christmas.png";   // Christmas
            break;
        case 11:
            src = "Images/Logos/Thankgiving.png";   // Thanksgiving
            break;
        case 10:
            src = "Images/Logos/Halloween.png";   // Halloween
            break;
        case 7:
            src = "Images/Logos/Fourth.png";   // Fourth of July
            break;
        case 2:
            src = "Images/Logos/Valentines.png";   // Valentines Day
            break;
        case 1:
            src = "Images/Logos/NewYear.png";   // New Years
            break;
    }

    img.src = src;
});
```

It works to an extent.  It will change the image on my "Dashboard" view, which is where the application opens to upon starting up (In case that matters), however, it makes the image on all other views appear as if it doesn't exist.

Hope someone has either ran into the same issue or if someone can tell me if there is something wrong with my JS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well make the paths absolute instead of relative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that I was writing my Paths incorrectly.

**Correct Paths:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var d = new Date();
var Month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var img = document.getElementById("logo");
var src;

switch (Month) {
    default:
        src = "../Images/Logos/default.png";   // Set Default Logo
        break;
    case 12:
        src = "../Images/Logos/Christmas.png";   // Christmas
        break;
    case 11:
        src = "../Images/Logos/Thanksgiving.png";   // Thanksgiving
        break;
    case 10:
        src = "../Images/Logos/Halloween.png";   // Halloween
        break;
    case 7:
        src = "../Images/Logos/Fourth.png";   // Fourth of July
        break;
    case 2:
        src = "../Images/Logos/Valentines.png";   // Valentines Day
        break;
    case 1:
        src = "../Images/Logos/NewYear.png";   // New Years
        break;
}

img.src = src;
```

});

Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the src path is correct? You have an '~' in your .html while there is not in the script. However, I am used to move the 'default' case at the bottom of switches.. don't know if it could solve the problem.